# Nested ng repeat, natural sorting keys

Tags: angularjs, key, iteration, natural-sort

I have data which can take the following format:

```
var data = 
{
0:[1:"a", 2:"b", 11:"c", 22:"d"],
1:[1:"e",2:"f",11:"g",22:"h"]
}
```

If I do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">
    <div ng-repeat="(innerKey, innerValue) in value">
        {{innerKey}}
    </div>
    <br/>
</div>
```

This will give me:

```
1 11 2 22
1 11 2 22
```

since it is sorting by string comparison on the keys, not the numeric value of the key

What I really want is:

```
1 2 11 22
1 2 11 22
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: May be this will point you at some right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287716/skip-ng-repeat-json-ordering-in-angular-js/19300860#19300860

Comment: The data is not guaranteed to be sorted in _anyway_. The order of keys is going to depend on the implementation (V8 or Spidermonkey) but that is not something you should rely on. You should extract the keys in your controller and sort them in the way you want instead of using the `(k, v) in data` form for `ng-repeat`.

Comment: I do not think that what you have posted is correct JS -- I mean `var data` part.

Comment: @Cherniv Thanks for the great thread, I think this will work for me.

Comment: Yes, this is really simple and useful solution, it worked for me!

Comment: @Cherniv, one small thing I had to do at the end was splice the keys in a (-1,1) fashion to remove the hashkey value since it messes up iterations. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you could restructure the data a little bit, you could try this. I removed the nested data to simplify the core issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/rsmclaug/BHF9C/

Also, the data as-is is not valid array syntax.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:'key'">
    {{item.key}} - {{item.value}}
</div>

$scope.data = [
    {key: 1, value: "a"}, 
    {key: 12, value: "c"}, 
    {key: 2, value: "b"}, 
    {key: 22, value:"d"}
];
```