# ng-repeat gets wrong $index when sorting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have simple object:

```
"socials": {
  "f": "#/facebook/",
  "B": "#/behance/",
  "d": "#/dribble/",
  "L": "#/linkedin/",
  "P": "#/pinterest/"
}
```

When I try to use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.socials"` it sorts like this: B L P d f.

$index catches wrong index, just as it is ordered by already. How can I order it correctly as it is in jSON file? Or maybe how can I get correct index to use `orderBy: correctIndex`? I found a fiddle that shows an issue exactly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zMjVp/

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS sorting by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14478106/angularjs-sorting-by-property)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287716/skip-ng-repeat-json-ordering-in-angular-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ngRepeat` iterates over object keys in alphabetical order to manage tracking items by $index ([see the code for ngRepeat on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L299)).

To control the order of iteration in `ngRepeat` you should convert your object structure into an Array which has guaranteed iteration ordering:

**JavaScript:**

```
var jsonData = {
    "socials": {
        "f": "#/facebook/",
        "B": "#/behance/",
        "d": "#/dribble/",
        "L": "#/linkedin/",
        "P": "#/pinterest/"
    }
};

var socialsList = [];
angular.forEach(jsonData.socials, function(value, key){
    socialsList.push({
        key: key,
        value: value
    });
});
$scope.socialsList = socialsList;
```

**HTML:**

Then update your HTML to iterate over the list instead of the object.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in socialsList">
    <p> {{item.key}} : {{item.value}} </p> 
</div>
```

*NOTE:*

Unless you're using the `delete` operator you can generally rely on the order of the `for...in` loop. It's not *guaranteed*, but it's generally reliable. [See the MDN documentation on for...in loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description)

Comment: I think you meant socialsList variable when pushing