# ng-repeat on object. Avoiding default ordering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iterator, angularjs-ng-repeat

When **ng-repeat** in **angularJS** iterates over keys of and **object**, it dafaults the order of keys as *alphabetic*. We are in a situation where we cannot use the collection as an array. Can someone suggest a *proper solution* where we can iterate over the keys of the object in the order in which they appear and **not the default alphabetic order**.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you written something in your controller/HTML ?

Comment: Share us your code so we can help you.

Comment: I don't actually think that's true. ng-repeat over an object keys iterates using the order the keys are defined. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0d6Rzl5gotP6USiGdYv9?p=preview)

As an aside, it is not possible to orderBy object keys or values in ng-repeat. If you need an orderBy, you will have to create an array of the keys or values and ng-repeat over that.

Comment: There is some "solutions" of this at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287716/skip-ng-repeat-json-ordering-in-angular-js