# Angular function default data out of order on view

Tags: angularjs, function, scope

I'm working on a scheduling app with Angularjs and Firebase.  For some reason when I write my function to set the default data the days are in order Mon, Tues, Wed, Thurs, Fri but my view shows the days as Fri, Mon, Thurs, Tues, Wed.  Not sure why or how to fix, every thing else seems to be working fine.
[image]

app.js

```
    angular.module('scheduleApp', ['firebase'])
    create our main controller and get access to firebase
    .controller('mainController', function($scope, $firebase) {


      var ref = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/days");  
      var fb = $firebase(ref);

      var syncObject = fb.$asObject();

      syncObject.$bindTo($scope, 'days');

       $scope.reset = function() {    

fb.$set({
  monday: {
    name: 'Monday',
    slots: {

      100: {
        time: '10:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      110: {
        time: '11:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      120: {
        time: '12:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      130: {
        time: '1:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      140: {
        time: '2:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      150: {
        time: '3:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      160: {
        time: '4:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      170: {
        time: '5:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      180: {
        time: '6:00pm',
        booked: false
      }
 }
  },
  tuesday: {
    name: 'Tuesday',
    slots: {

      100: {
        time: '10:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      110: {
        time: '11:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      120: {
        time: '12:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      130: {
        time: '1:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      140: {
        time: '2:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      150: {
        time: '3:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      160: {
        time: '4:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      170: {
        time: '5:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      180: {
        time: '6:00pm',
        booked: false
      }
    }
  },
  wednesday: {
    name: 'Wednesday',
    slots: {

      100: {
        time: '10:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      110: {
        time: '11:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      120: {
        time: '12:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      130: {
        time: '1:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      140: {
        time: '2:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      150: {
        time: '3:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      160: {
        time: '4:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      170: {
        time: '5:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      180: {
        time: '6:00pm',
        booked: false
      }
  }
      },
      thursday: {
    name: 'Thursday',
    slots: {

      100: {
        time: '10:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      110: {
        time: '11:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      120: {
        time: '12:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      130: {
        time: '1:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      140: {
        time: '2:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      150: {
        time: '3:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      160: {
        time: '4:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      170: {
        time: '5:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      180: {
        time: '6:00pm',
        booked: false
      }
  }

      },

  friday: {
    name: 'Friday',
    slots: {

      100: {
        time: '10:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      110: {
        time: '11:00am',
        booked: false
      },
      120: {
        time: '12:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      130: {
        time: '1:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      140: {
        time: '2:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      150: {
        time: '3:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      160: {
        time: '4:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      170: {
        time: '5:00pm',
        booked: false
      },
      180: {
        time: '6:00pm',
        booked: false
        }
      }
     }
       });    

      };

    });
```

index.html

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
         <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular Scheduling</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.0/journal/bootstrap.m    in.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

       <!-- JS -->
       <!-- load Angular, Firebase, Firebase Angular Library, and  custom    app.js -->
       <script   src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.1.1/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
       <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container" ng-app="scheduleApp" ng-controller="mainController">

       <div class="page-header text-center">       
      <h1>Schedule City</h1>        
      </div>

      <div class="row times">

      <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" ng-repeat="day in days">

       <h2>{{ day.name }} </h2>

       <div class="time-slot" ng-repeat="slot in day.slots">       
     <input type="checkbox" id="{{ day.name }}-{{ $index}}" ng- model="slot.booked" ng-disabled="slot.booked">
     <label for="{{ day.name }}-{{ $index }}">{{ slot.time }}<br>
     <span ng-if="slot.booked">Booked</span>
     <span ng-if="!slot.booked">Available</span>
   </label>
   </div>
     </div>    

    </div>

     <p class="text-center">    
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="reset()">Reset</a>
    </p>

    </div>  
    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `order` field to your data. Eg

```
  monday: {
    name: 'Monday',
    order: '1',
    slots: {
 etc...
```

and then do

```
ng-repeat="day in days | orderBy:'order'"
```

Update: As you don't have an array, this may not work. See *iterating over object properties* in the [documentation for ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for some tips.

One idea is to instead define the order yourself in a new variable, iterate over that and use it to retrieve the correct values from the original object.

```
$scope.dayNames = ["monday", "tuesday"...];
```

and then do

```
ng-repeat="dayName in dayNames"
```

and then grab the object using days[dayName], e. g.

```
ng-repeat="slot in days[dayName].slots"
```

Update: Like this:

```
  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center" ng-repeat="dayName in dayNames">

   <h2>{{ days[dayName].name }} </h2>

   <div class="time-slot" ng-repeat="slot in days[dayName].slots">       
 <input type="checkbox" id="{{ days[dayName].name }}-{{ $index}}" ng- model="slot.booked" ng-disabled="slot.booked">
 <label for="{{ days[dayName].name }}-{{ $index }}">{{ slot.time }}<br>
 <span ng-if="slot.booked">Booked</span>
 <span ng-if="!slot.booked">Available</span>
....
```

Comment: Greatly appreciate the thorough response.  I've made the updated changes and it eliminates the names of the days all together and only allows me to select time slots from the first day's column.  Even if I click on a time slot on the 3rd, 4th day, the time slot is highlighted and marked as booked only on the first column.  You've definitely helped me get in the right direction though.

Comment: @sp312 could you show what you've tried with this solution so far?

Comment: With out rewriting the code to change it to an array I was not able to find the correct way to fix this.  I realized angular automatically orders object alphabetically so just for the sake of my practice I just did a cheat and added letters in alphabetical order in front of each object like so.  Won't leave like this of course but at least I now know the issue which will make it easier to fix.  
$set({
  amonday: {
    name: 'Monday',
    slots: {

  btuesday: {
    name: 'Tuesday',
    slots: {

Comment: It seems the best way to fix this would be to add the object's key as these links show. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287716/skip-ng-repeat-json-ordering-in-angular-js

http://stephenradford.me/keep-your-objects-order-the-same-in-angularjs/

Which I'll try asap and report back.

Comment: Honest I'm not sure.  With your code I added  

<div class="col-xs-2 text-center" ng-repeat="dayName in dayOrder">
      <h2> days[dayName] </h2>

and 

var syncObject = fb.$asObject();
 syncObject.$bindTo($scope, 'dayOrder');
$scope.dayOrder = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"];
  
   $scope.reset = function() {    

    fb.$set({

      monday: {
        name: 'Mon',
        slots: {      
Which gives me a blank page.  The closest I got was with the first solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287716/skip-ng-repeat-json-ordering-in-angular-js

Comment: Which displays the day names in order but in boxes with additional words like ue: monday, :key, key, val..instead of just the names.  Sorry I'm probably confusing you now.  Will continue to work on it and reply if i get it.

Comment: While updating my text in my html file to match yours, do I keep the app.js code the same as your first suggestion using $scope.dayOrder?  I've tried that and other variations and i cant get the h2 curly brackets to show the day names in the array or at all once I modify it to match your code.  http://codepen.io/sevilayha/pres/vEEmMX You can try here if you like to see if it works but you've already helped so much.  Thank you.

Comment: @sp312 like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvXWBP updated my answer to match your code better

Comment: You are the best.  Thank you so very much for working with me to understand this.