# Dynamic data table in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to create a dynamic data table in angular js which has first column with check box. The data would be in Json format as below,

```
$scope.items = [
        { "id": "1", "lastName": "Test1", "firstName": "Test", "email": "test1@example.com" },
        { "id": "2", "lastName": "Test2", "firstName": "Test", "email": "test2@example.com" },
        { "id": "3", "lastName": "Test3", "firstName": "Test", "email": "test3@example.com" },
        { "id": "4", "lastName": "Test4", "firstName": "Test", "email": "test4@example.com" },
        { "id": "5", "lastName": "Test5", "firstName": "Test", "email": "test5@example.com" }
    ];
```

The id would be a column with checkbox and all other columns will have the data in it.
The headers of the table are also dynamic and so does the column.

Comment: How to create a dynamic table in angularjs with first column as checkbox using above json?

Answer (score 0):

If the columns are dynamic

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:1">
   <th ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">{{key}}</th>
   <td  ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">
    <div ng-show="key == 'id'">
     <input type="checkbox" value={{value}} name="id" />
    </div>
    <div ng-show="key != 'id'">
     {{value}}
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

ng-repeat does JSON ordering for keys, To get ID first follow skipping the JSON ordering [Skip JSON ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19300860/6919997) (because your JSON has ID first after skipping JSON ordering you will get ID first)

Comment: The columns are dynamic so I cannot write,

 <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>

Comment: This is a very helpful answer.