# Angularjs how to prevent ordering in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using a json array in AngularJS `ng-repeat`. I observed that it orders the input that overrides what I have in my html. Is there any way to prevent this ordering to happen?

Here is my code (See it in [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/af1TsBBA3CtSZq8eAx5R?p=preview)):

```
<body ng-controller="Controller">
  <div ng-repeat="x in data">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-show="x.Project == 'ABC'" ng-model="x.Show"><b ng-show="x.Project == 'ABC'"> project ABC is wonderful</b>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-show="x.Project == 'DEF'" ng-model="x.Show"><b ng-show="x.Project == 'DEF'"> How is this EFG?</b>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-show="x.Project == 'IJK'" ng-model="x.Show"><b ng-show="x.Project == 'IJK'"> This is my IJK project</b>
  </div>
  <br> {{data}}
</body>
```

And the ata:

```
$scope.data = [{
    "Project": "IJK",
    "Show": "true"
  },
  {
    "Project": "DEF",
    "Show": "false"
  },
  {
    "Project": "ABC",
    "Show": "true"
  }
];
```

I found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287716/skip-ng-repeat-json-ordering-in-angular-js), but this is using an outside function but I am looking for some better way if possible.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why don't you just make an `ng-repeat` over `data` and use its content for generating dinamically the `intput`s instead of showing/hiding the three of them in every iteration (by the way, do you know you are generating 9 inputs, and showing only 3?). This would show the values in the same order of the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not at all clear...

The way you approach it would not at all scale if more projects arrive, so try to describe your end goal rather than where you are at now...

If Your only ever interested in knowing something about those 3 particular projects regardless of how many the server returns, convert it to a map and then then just lookup:

```
  $scope.map = $scope.data.reduce(function(map, next) {
    map[next.Project] = next;
    return map;
  }, {});

  <div><input type="checkbox" ng-model="map['ABC'].Show"><b> project ABC is wonderful</b></div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" ng-model="map['DEF'].Show"><b> How is this EFG?</b></div>
  <div><input type="checkbox" ng-model="map['IJK'].Show"><b> This is my IJK project</b></div>
```

If the list is dynamic (you may get any number of projects to show)... Sort it!...

```
  <div ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy:'Project'">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.Show"><b> Bla {{x.Project}} bla</b>
  </div>
```

Or in code if you need more control:

```
  var sorted = $scope.data.slice(0);
  sorted.sort(function(left, right) {
    var l = left.Project.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    var r = right.Project.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    if (l < r) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (l > r) {
      return 1;
    }

    // names must be equal
    return 0;
  });
  $scope.sorted = sorted;

  <div ng-repeat="x in sorted">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.Show"><b> Bla {{x.Project}} bla</b>
  </div>
```

Finally, if you wish to change the text on a pr. project bases in this case, either need another lookup:

```
  $scope.text = {
    ABC: "project ABC is wonderful",
    DEF: "How is this EFG?",
    IJK: "This is my IJK project",
  }

  <div ng-repeat="x in ...">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.Show"><b> {{text[x.Project]}}</b>
  </div>
```

OR to enrich the model:

```
  $scope.enriched = sorted.map(function(item){
    item.text = textmap[item.Project];
    return item;
  })

  <div ng-repeat="x in enriched">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.Show"><b> {{x.text}}</b>
  </div>
```

But I can't tell which of the solutions you are looking for?

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZTKe9QMWnEiSiCXUb9Gz?p=preview

I should also note that I converted the "Show" property into booleans rather than text, as it appears you wan't the checkbox to bind to it I assumed you wanted that...

If the input json comes with text you can use ng-true-value/ng-false-value, see the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

or map the values.

The samples are easier to explain with just booleans so ill keep em that way.

Comment: Agree with you. Only one thing to notice here: in the solution where the list is dynamic this code `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.Show"><b> Bla {{x.Project}} bla</b>` should be `<input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.Show[someIndexHere]"><b> Bla {{x.Project}} bla</b>` in order to bind properly the model of every project. Notice the `someIndexHere` part.

Comment: Considering what he did in the question, I assume he wish to have the checkboxes checked if Show is true and not cheeked if false... (considering the way he binds them) which is they way the samples I provided works... But again... The question is not at all clear on the end goal... If we where to bind as you say, it would be indexing into a string with the value of true/false, not sure what that would get us...

Comment: @Jens, i regret for not conveying the need in right way. All i want is, the display order should be what i am giving for "<input> type" , not what angular does internally. Anyway, the "$scope.map =" method is doing exactly what i want and i am taking this for my project. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Make an `ng-repeat` over `data` and use its content for generating dynamically the `intput`s instead of showing/hiding the three of them in every iteration. This would show the values in the same order of the JSON, like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in data">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="x.Show[$index]"><b>Project {{x.Project}} is Present</b>
</div>
```

Notice here how the model is created dynamically too, in the object `x.Show`. This object will have now an index for every project and in that index the property will be `true`|`false` depending on the value of the project checkbox.

See a working [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/af1TsBBA3CtSZq8eAx5R?p=preview)

Comment: Yes its working. But what if the text is not same for all three. For example , ABC=>'project ABC is wonderful',EFG=>'How is this EFG?', IJK=>'This is my IJK project'. And i want to print in order of (EFG,ABC,IJK)

Comment: In that case, the best option would be to have another two attributes in the JSON `data` indicating the name of the project and the order, for instance: `$scope.data = [{
    "Project": "IJK",
    "Show": "true",
    "Name" : "This is my IJK project",
    "order" : 3
  }];` (there is only one object in this sample, the other two object would follow the same pattern). Whit this you would show the name like this: `{{x.Name}}` and order the `ng-repeat` like this: `ng-repeat="x in data | orderBy: 'order'"`

Comment: @sand if what you described is the real case, update you question, so I Can update the answer with the proper code.

Comment: hi @lealceldeiro, i can not change the input json. I have update question and plunkr also.

Comment: @sand, I wonder, Why can not you change the JSON data? If it is coming from server or you need it to do other tasks... but anyway you want to show it in this specific order, make a copy of the JSON and transform it as I described in my previous comment. Is not that an option either? Anyways, let me see how can I solve the issue with these conditions.